# Whenever I put the margin on either the circle or the square element, the element get disappers. Can I know the reason for this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Jquery</title>
      <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <style type = "text/css">
         #circle {
         width: 150px;
         height: 150px;
         border-radius: 50%;
         background-color: green
         **margin: 10px;**
         }
         .square {
         width: 150px;
         height: 150px;
         background-color: red
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "circle"> </div>
      <div class = "square"> </div>
      <div class = "square"> </div>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         $("#circle").click(function() {    
         alert($("body").css("width"));
         })
      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to separate the square and circle with margin of 10px but when I put a margin of 10px, the circle disappears but why?

Answer (score 1):

You have some invalid `HTML`, please see the corrected code & evidence it seems to work just fine when the `HTML` is valid.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Jquery</title>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
#circle {

  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  
}

.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="circle"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#circle").click(function() {
      alert($("body").css("width"));
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztb49fkL/)

The sections of invalid `HTML` are as follows:

**Remove the two asterisks**

```
background-color: green
**margin: 10px;**
}
```

**There is no starting head tag**

```
</head>
```

**There needs to be a final semicolon**

```
background-color: red
```

**A final semi colon would be good here too**

```
$("#circle").click(function() {    
alert($("body").css("width"));
})
```

Comment: Thank you, missing semicolon was the problem.